# android volley - can't read data from local host

Tags: java, android, request, localhost, android-volley

I wrote android app to read json using volley.

If i use example URL from internet - i don't have problem, the data is read. But when i try to read data from local host, I am getting an error.
The same data i can see in web browser in my emulator.
my URL: "http://10.0.2.2/volley_sample/get_data.php"

my code:

```
     private void sendGetRequest() {

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
       
        String url = "http://10.0.2.2/volley_sample/get_data.php"; //it doesn't work

        //String url ="https://reqres.in/api/users/2"; //it works

      // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the first 10 characters of the response string.
                        get_response_text.setText("Response is: " + response.substring(0, 10));
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                get_response_text.setText("That didn't work!");
            }
        });

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

adres "http://10.0.2.2/volley_sample/get_data.php" works in web browser in my emulator.
I tried also "http://192.168....", "127.0.0.1....", "localhost/volley_sample...." etc., and neither works.

adres "https://reqres.in/api/users/2" (example from internet) work without problem.
ofc. i added `"<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>"`

I have no idea what I am doing wrong :(

Comment: Allowed clear text traffic?

Comment: `If i use example URL from internet ` http or https?

Comment: from internet is https.
Local is http

Comment: Well you could have said more now. Try an internet url with http to see that it will not go. And why didnt you react on my first comment?

Comment: my script to read:
<?php
$data=array("data_1"=>"Value 1","data_2"=>"Value 2","data_3"=>"Value 3");
echo json_encode($data);

Comment: It has nothing to do with your script but with the protocol you use.

Comment: does that mean i can't use http? How can i change it?

Comment: Again you are not reacting on my first comment.